# Data Transformation in SQL: Removing Account Information From Data Set Based On a Value in a Column

Tags: sql, r, dataframe

I'm looking for a similar SQL Statement to the `any` statement in [R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/any). What I have is a time-series data set that begins in 2014 and ends in 2020. I have a column that identifies if, in 2016, individuals voluntarily or involuntarily changed a drug. What I want to do is completely remove any individuals that involuntarily changed a drug. In R what I would do is group by the individual's ID and delete all IDs from the data set if the DrugChange column is 'Involuntarily'. My R code would look like this:

```
df<-df%>%group_by(ID)%>%filter(!any(DrugChange=='Involuntarily'))
```

In SQL I've been searching around for a somewhat simple solution, and (stupidly) thought just using a `WHERE` statement would work, but all it does is remove one row not all rows. Is there a way I can use a `WHERE` statement or is there a better method?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  You should not depend on database people having experience with R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you are looking to take a subset of rows such that if any row for an ID has `Involuntarily` in the `DrugChange` column then all rows for that ID should be excluded so in the example in the Note at the end all rows for ID 1 would be excluded and all rows for ID 2 would be kept.

**1) windowing function** Using the test data in the Note at the end and an SQL windowing function create a column `ok` which is 1 for every row of an ID not having any `Involutarily` in the `DrugChange` column and then pick only those rows .  We have removed the `ok` column but if you want it omit the [-1].

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select * from (
  select not max(DrugChange = 'Involuntarily') over (partition by ID) ok, * 
  from df
 ) where ok")[-1]
```

giving:

```
  DrugChange ID
1          X  2
2          X  2
```

**1a)** This could be written in terms of a CTE like this:

```
sqldf("with inner as (
  select not max(DrugChange = 'Involuntarily') over (partition by ID) ok, *
  from df
) 
select * from inner where ok")[-1]
```

**2) join** An alternate approach is to generate one row per ID with the ok value and then join it to `df` if ok is 1.

```
sqldf("select a.* 
  from df a join (select ID, not max(DrugChange = 'Involuntarily') ok 
                  from df 
                  group by ID) b on a.ID = b.ID and b.ok")
```

giving:

```
  DrugChange ID
1          X  2
2          X  2
```

**2a)** We could also write this in terms of a CTE like this:

```
sqldf("with right as (
  select ID, not max(DrugChange = 'Involuntarily') ok 
  from df 
  group by ID
)
select a.* from df a join right b on a.ID = b.ID and b.ok")
```

**3) in** A different approach is to use `in` as shown here:

```
sqldf("select *
  from df
  where id not in (select distinct id from df where DrugChange = 'Involuntarily')")
```

giving:

```
  DrugChange ID
1          X  2
2          X  2
```

It will also work without the `distinct` keyword.

**3a)** We could also write it with a CTE like this:

```
sqldf("with ids as (
    select distinct id from df where DrugChange = 'Involuntarily'
  )
  select * from df where id not in ids")
```

### Note

Test data used.

```
df <- data.frame(DrugChange = c("Involuntarily", "X", "X", "X"), ID = c(1,1,2,2))
```

Comment: This is a great response and answer. I'm playing around with your 1 and 3 answer and trying to implement it into my code, but the way my code is setup is with 3 CTEs. When I try to use your code with my mine I cannot run it. So I'm wondering can these codes, as is, be used with CTEs? I can upload my SQL code if needed, but it is a pretty long code. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I have added CTE versions of all solutions but these may not address your further problem as without a minimal reproducible example as per instructions at top of r tag it is not clear what the further problem is

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when DrugChange = 'Involuntarily' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```